# Twitter Bootstrap + Mootools + JQuery.NoConflict() problems while trying to use popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools, twitter-bootstrap

I have mootools and Twitter Bootstrap (which uses JQuery for their Javascript capabilities) working nearly "well" using JQuery.NoConflict() inside the bootstrap-dropdown.js .

Well, now I'm trying to use bootstrap-popover.js and it's not working as smoothly as bootstrap-dropdown.js. Well I guess that it's a compatibility mode issue that I cannot understand pretty well.

I have this javascript with error:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  $('td[rel=popover]')
    .popover({
      offset: 10,
      live: true
    })
    .click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
    })
})
</script>
```

And the error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function
```

**EDIT:**

I've successfully used popover before (but not with mootools) and i tried to repeat the same way and codes. Just before this javascript code with error, i'm linking the files like this (which are successfully loading):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/html5.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap-alerts.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap-twipsy.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap.css" />
```

I know that it should be better between `<head></head>` but it should work as well inside `<body>` And it is working for other `bootstrap-alerts.js` and `dropdown`.
Also, I'm calling the popover this way in a `<table>`:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Título</th>
        <th>Data</th>
        <th>Horário</th>
        <th rel="popover" data-original-title="A title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?">Ticket Associado <img src="../img/alert-icon.gif"></th>
        <th>Entrar no Chat</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

And mootools are being called after twitter-Bootstrap/JQuery.

Any help? Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

erm. seems as if there's an issue with the twitter popover code, more likely than anything.

`Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function` - sounds as if the $ is not what you think it is. I thought the point of noConflict was to revert to using `jQuery()` and not `$` - the code that you post is not exactly doing that.

conversely - mootools, if loaded AFTER jquery and if of version 1.2.3 or higher, will NOT take over the `$` declaration and fallback to `document.id` instead.

when do you get the exception, runtime or when you interact with a popover element? do `console.log(window.$)` and see what has declared it, it sounds like it's a primitive object property and not a function.

do you run any specific mootools stuff that requires use of $? need more data than what you have provided.

one thing you may want to look at is the MooTools port of BootStrap here: http://dev.clientcide.com/?version=MooTools%20Bootstrap - still a work in progress but it has the important stuff.

Comment: Chirstoff, I've added some more information about the confs and environment. I appreciate your help and patience :)

Comment: where is mootools being loaded and which version? what happens when you do console.log(window.$) as well as console.log($.toString()) - jquery or mootools has it or is something else? you also say you have used it inside of the bootstrap-dropdown. the code provided does for the popover not look like it's safe - it relies on $ being jquery.